# Track Employee usage: breadcrumbs style

Tags: history-tracking

Is there a way to track what emlpoyee has been doing in an "x" time, or log?

We have an emlpoyee, which we need to let go. We want to know if there is a way we can track his usage of SF from that point on (or other)

weather he did export? global searches? or other important information, in order to keep our records safe.

EDIT: I am NOT referring to the User object. I refer to ALL his doings (create/edit/delete all other data/objects)

Comment: I'm not sure that user logs (user level audit trail ) is present in SF at this point. [check this](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BqrvAAC)

Comment: There was an idea on the ideaExchange that is similar to what you are looking for https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BqQGAA0 and it states it was delivered in this last release and refers to this doc here: http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_security_elf.htm#topic-title